# Best regex to match IEEE Time Stamp format in Python

Tags: python, regex

I did some searching but didn't find this specifically, and I'm sure it's going to be a quick answer.

I have a python script parsing IEEE date and time stamps out of strings, but I think I'm using python's match objects wrong.

```
import re
stir = "foo_2015-07-07-17-58-26.log"
timestamp = re.search("([0-9]+-){5}[0-9]+", stir).groups()
print timestamp
```

Produces

```
58-
```

When my intent is to get

```
2015-07-07-17-58-26
```

Is there a pre-canned regex that would work better here?  Am I getting tripped up on re's capture groups?  Why is the length of the groups() tuple only 1?

**Edit**

I was misinterpreting the way capture groups work in python's re module - there is only one set of parentheses in the statement, so the re module returned the most recently grabbed capture group - the "58-".

The way I ended up doing it was by referencing group(0), as Dawg suggests below.

```
timestamp = re.search("([0-9]+-){5}[0-9]+", stir)

print timestamp.group(0)
2015-07-07-17-58-26
```

Comment: You need individual capture group

Comment: Just a note:  regular expression could help grepping for time stamps, but don't forget validating them as legal dates and times.  If it's not valid, you may consider rejecting it as a match, or deal with the exception.  This validation part is not the ideal job of regex, despite probably many telling you so, and trying to demonstrate their mad h4xx0r ski11z by actually doing so ;)

Comment: @CongMa I'm actually doing something way dirtier - I'm just straight up removing the dashes and calling the whole thing an int, then I'm comparing it to other IEEE date / time stamps and seeing which one is more to determine which is more recent.

Comment: @Locane  I was kinda expecting someone come up with a "validation-by-regex" trick and getting modded up to heaven ;) So far, none yet ;)

Comment: Just to make a suggestion: the regex `([0-9]+-){5}[0-9]+` matches [lots of things](https://regex101.com/r/vW0hX9/1) that are not a time stamp. You may want to use `(\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){5})` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a single capture group or groups:

```
(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF3cL1/1)

Or, use nested capture groups:

```
>>> re.search(r'(\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){5})', 'foo_2015-07-07-17-58-26.log')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100b49dc8>
>>> _.group(1)
'2015-07-07-17-58-26'
```

Or, you can use your pattern and just use `group(0)` instead of `groups()`:

```
>>> re.search("([0-9]+-){5}[0-9]+", "foo_2015-07-07-17-58-26.log").group(0)
'2015-07-07-17-58-26'
```

Or, use `findall` with an additional capture group (and the other a non capture group):

```
>>> re.findall("((?:[0-9]+-){5}[0-9]+)", 'foo_2015-07-07-17-58-26.log')
['2015-07-07-17-58-26']
```

But that will find the digits that are not part of the timestamp.

Comment: Is it not possible to use the (stuff){5} matching pattern?  Do I need to use the \d or [0-9]+ typed out that way as a limitation of python or RE?

Comment: You can do `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the timestamp in one match object, i think this should work

```html
\d{4}(?:\d{2}){5}
```

then use group() or group(0)

also, match.groups actually returns the number of group objects, you should try .group() instead (your code would still not work though because you grouped the 5 sets of numbers in and the final -58 would be omitted

Answer (score 0):

I'd use below:

```
_(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}).
```

_ and . to mark the starting and the end.

```
import re
r = r'_(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}).'
s = 'some string'
lst = re.findall(s,r)
```

[link](https://regex101.com/r/hT4cY4/1#python)

Answer (score 0):

You might want

```
re.findall(r"([0-9-]+)", stir)


>>> import re
>>> stir = "foo_2015-07-07-17-58-26.log"
>>> re.findall(r"([0-9-]+)", stir)
['2015-07-07-17-58-26']
```